# Make the "Top X%" in the user profile more crawler-friendly

Tags: bug, profile-page, reputation-leagues

It's fun sometimes to go through the [Wayback Machine](http://archive.org) and see how your reputation has changed over time.

Today I've just noticed that archive.org misses the "Top X%" from a profile when it archives the page. [Example](https://web.archive.org/web/20141226105257/https://stackoverflow.com/users/1269037/dan-dascalescu).

[image]

Comment: Seems to work sometimes e.g. https://web.archive.org/web/20140509045425/http://stackoverflow.com/users/1269037/dan-dascalescu

Comment: I think that quite often the job calculating those get "stuck" so the number isn't available. Don't think it got anything to do about crawling rules. :/